# Reading claim attributes from SAMl in Adfs

Tags: c#, adfs, siteminder, federation

i am trying integration between CA federation manager and ADFS. Where ADFS is acting as service provider and Federation manager as IDP. I am able to read nameid which is passed from Federation manager to ADFS as claim attribute. But i am not able to read other SAML attributes which are sent by Federation manager such as GivenName, Surname. I have tried all option , please assist. I can see the SAML attribute being posted to ADFS.

Testing

I am not able to read givenname as claim attribute in adfs.

Comment: i am reading the claims in adfs using WIF sample application

Comment: did any one find the answer ?